# Where are these two video game songs from?

Tags: game-identification, game-music-identification, descent-1

I have been playing through a custom mission in 1994's [descent-1](/questions/tagged/descent-1), a 6DoF shooter. The community has created a number of custom missions throughout the years, and the particular one I am playing through has custom MIDI music. I want to try my hand at remixing two songs in the set, however no one knows what they are. I have reached out to another member of the community, who told me they composed 3 songs out of 23, **but the other 20 are from other games, as far as they know**. I have also checked with the original mod author, who unfortunately does not have the source material anymore, and does not remember, as the mission was created many years ago.

As such, I am hoping Arqade can identify the following two songs:

The custom mission in question is Descent Vignettes by DarkFlameWolf. [You can find the mission here.](https://sectorgame.com/dxma/mission/?m=560)

Comment: For anybody who might consider to VTC, this was discussed on [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16598/124566)

Comment: When is the custom mission pack from? If it's contemporary with the original game, that might narrow down the possibilities a little bit. Do you know where any of the other 20 songs came from? It seems likely to me that there'd be a lot of overlap in games or at least genres, so identifying others might lead you to these two as well.

Comment: @qazmlpok the .txt for the mod claims it was started September 2008 and finished August 2009.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Both of these tracks come off the 1993 beat 'em up Battletoads & Double Dragon (two of my favourite franchises from back in the day). The game was developed by the legendary British game studio Rare.

I do believe Descent Vignettes Level 1 track is a modified version of "On da missile", and Descent Vignettes Level 15 track is a modified version of "Crazy ride".

Listen for yourself, in case age has gotten the better of my ears:

Comment: I'm in agreement on this answer. They sound quite similar to the songs you identified. The "on da missile" track especially I can hear the similarities

Comment: The chances of ears failing me have drastically gone down - phew! :)

Comment: @Ulfdróttin, you're incredible. Those are the two songs in question! Well done, your ears did not fail! Your input is so appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Knowing this, I was able to find this site: https://www.khinsider.com/midi/snes/battletoads-and-double-dragon that has midi versions of those songs. Level-5-2 relates to on da missile, and level-7 is crazy ride!